# using REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL but on projection I'm getting "()"

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using Cloudera - quickstat 5.4. I have a file having data in each line like:

> 323.81.303.680 - - [25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500] "GET /download/download6.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U;
>   Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19"

and in apache pig i'm using script like :

```
A= LOAD 'weblog.txt' using TextLoader() as (line:chararray);
B= FOREACH A GENERATE 
FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] “(.+?)” (\\S+) (\\S+) “([^”]*)” “([^”]*)”')) AS (remoteAddr: chararray, remoteLogname: chararray, user: chararray, time:chararray, request: chararray, status:int,bytes_string:chararray,referrer: chararray, browser: chararray);

DUMP B;
```

Output of above query gives output like

() 
()

Can anyone please tell what wrong i'm doing? is regex all right?

Comment: Do you really have curly quotes in the regex?

Comment: no pretend these curly quotes as ''.

Comment: Add `, line` at the end, after `chararray)` and before `;`.

Comment: @stribizhev : yea it worked thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `, line` at the end, after chararray) and before `;`:

```
A= LOAD 'weblog.txt' using TextLoader() as (line:chararray);
B= FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(
    REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] "(.+?)" (\\S+) (\\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"')) 
     AS (remoteAddr: chararray, remoteLogname: chararray, user: chararray, time:chararray, request: chararray, status:int,bytes_string:chararray,referrer: chararray, browser: chararray)
       , line;

DUMP B;
```

As for the regex, it matches the example string well, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dF2yM3/1).